# Access issues to Power BI report. User identity is different

Tags: powerbi, azure-ad-b2b

Access issues to Power BI report. User identity is different.
The one that says "Invitation accepted" can not access reports. The one that doesn't have that but says "Manage B2B collaboration" can view reports. What is the difference in these and has one been invited incorrectly? How do i fix?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI integrates with Azure Active Directory Business-to-business (Azure AD B2B) to allow secure distribution of Power BI content to guest users outside the organization – while still maintaining control and governing access to internal data.
When you want to share a report with external user and if the user is not already a guest in your tenant, they are not invited, An email is sent to their email address that includes an invite to Azure AD b2b tenant.
the recipient will need ti accepts the invite to  Azure AD and is added as a Guest user in Azure AD tenant
The recipient is then redirected to the Power BI dashboard, report, or app, which are read-only for the user.

Once the external user has been invited to access resources a shadow account may be created for them in azure ad.
The first time they try to access a resources like a Power BI dashboard, they go through a consent process, which redeems the invitation.if they do not complete the consent, they cannot access any content. If they have trouble redeeming their invitation via the original link provided, an Azure AD administrator can resent a specific invitation link for them to redeem.
Ask azure admin to resend the invitation link

[Please refer this link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Accounts-Registration/Community-Account-Support/ta-p/680251#:%7E:text=Request%20your%20tenant%20admin%20to%20login%20to%20the,it.%20Select%20Security%20-%3E%20Permissions%20--%3E%20User%20Consent)